# Where in the ECMAScript specification is the return value from the await expression indicated?

Tags: ecmascript-6

I recently tried to figure out how promises works in ECMAScript. Most interested in the construction of AwaitExpression. In my opinion, it is the most incomprehensible and rather complicated in the specification.

Let me give some code:

```js
    /// Promise
    var promiseA = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve("Done!"), 10000)
      });
    /// Async/Await
    (async function(){
        var result = await promiseA;
        console.log(result); /// Output: "Done!"
    })();
    /// Promise.prototype.then
    promiseA.then(function (result){
        console.log(result); /// Output: "Done!"
    });
```

For me, as I said above, AwaitExpression is incomprehensible, I do not understand where the return of the value from promise is going. But I understand where the value from [[PromiseResult]] comes from and how the value [[PromiseResult]] from .then is passed into the argument to the callback function.

And there are some steps that unfortunately are not clear to me from [Await ()](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#await):

> 10. Remove asyncContext from the execution context stack and restore the execution context that is at the top of the execution context
>       stack as the running execution context.
> 11. Set the code evaluation state of asyncContext such that when evaluation is resumed with a Completion completion, the following
>       steps of the algorithm that invoked Await will be performed, with
>       completion available.
> 12. Return.
> 13. NOTE: This returns to the evaluation of the operation that had most previously resumed evaluation of asyncContext.

And part of the actions from the [Await Fulfilled Functions](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#await-fulfilled) is still not quite clear:

> 6. Resume the suspended evaluation of asyncContext using NormalCompletion(value) as the result of the operation that suspended
>      it.
> 7. Assert: When we reach this step, asyncContext has already been removed from the execution context stack and prevContext is the
>      currently running execution context.
> 8. Return undefined.

P.S How [Promise](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-promise-executor) and [.then](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-promise.prototype.then) are executed is clear to me, you can take this into account when explaining AwaitExpression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the critical thing to keep in mind when reading this is that the spec is free to start and stop execution of a given function right in the middle. When that happens, the function literally stops exactly where it is, but the *spec* steps keep going.

Given your example

```
(async function(){
  var result = await promiseA;
  console.log(result); /// Output: "Done!"
})();
```

in spec terms, this functions becomes:

1. Call the async function [`[[Call]]`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist)

   1. Do the normal prep work that function has
   2. [`OrdinaryCallEvaluateBody`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-ordinarycallevaluatebody)

      1. [`EvaluateBody` for async functions](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-async-function-definitions-EvaluateBody)

         1. Create the promise that gets returned by the async function
         2. [`AsyncFunctionStart`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-async-functions-abstract-operations-async-function-start)

            1. Initialize the promise object that gets returned
            2. Mark the execution context such that, when it fully completes, it will fulfill or reject the promise.
            3. Start executing the steps of the function, one at a time

               1. Eventually we get to the [`await`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#await) and do:
               2. Using the awaited promise, set it up so that the async function will resume execution when the promise finishes. (Step 2-9)
               3. "pop the execution context" which marks what step we were in the function, so that it can be started again later. (Step 10 in your quote)
               4. Set a flag on the execution context saying "the function is suspended, when it resumes, you will get the result of a promise, please resume the function as if the promise result was the completion value of the 'await'. (Step 11)
               5. Return. (Step 12).
         3. Return the promise for the async fn result.

The core thing to understand, is that Step 12 *is not returning into the async function*, because it was suspended. It is returning to `AsyncFunctionStart`, which then returns to `EvaluateBody`, which then returns the Promise result of the async function.

Then, later when the `promiseA` fulfills (due to the work of step 2-9 earlier)

1. Set the async function as the active execution context again ([Step 5 of "Await Fulfilled Functions"](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#await-fulfilled))
2. Resume execution with the result of the promise as the "completion" (Step 6). Because of the flags set on Step 11, this uses the completion value as the result of the await, and picks up execution of the async function until it returns, or awaits again.
3. Assert that the async function has finished some work for now (Step 7)
4. Return. (Step 8)

Answer (score 2):

It's the part

> using `NormalCompletion(value)` as the result of the operation that suspended it.

from the text you quoted. It will resume the execution of the `async function`, and make the `await` expression have the `value` as the result. Compare the `yield` operation and the generator `next()` method for reference.

Comment: Hmm, then what is the 8th step used for (`Return undefined.`)? Then, well, to get into the step that you are saying, you must perform this https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-promisereactionjob The 6 step will be what causes `Await Fulfilled Function`s. Yes, we get a promise. But this promise will not be used. Just look at the next step and see `Return NormalCompletion (empty)`. Maybe I missed something?

Comment: @MaximPro When it says to "*Resume the suspended evaluation*", it will perform "*the following steps of the algorithm that invoked Await*", i.e. continue with the code of the `async function` until the next `await`/`return`/uncaught `throw`. This will do its promise thing, then return to step 8, and return from the `onFulfilled` function.