# "Running execution context" in await expression promise handlers abstract closure according to the Spec

Tags: javascript, specifications, ecmascript-2021

I wanted to understand the internal mechanisms of a JavaScript engine for asynchronous functions, so I checked the [Spec](https://262.ecma-international.org/13.0/#await). For the rest of this question, I will refer to the linked version of the specification.

Section 6.2.3.1 describes this. Basically, a promise is created which is resolved to the expression that is awaited. The promise is then added resolving handlers via .then; The fulfillment handler is a function object created from an abstract closure which captures *asyncContext* which is the execution context associated to the asynchronous function. This abstract closure suspends the running execution context and restores asyncContext as the running execution context.

The thing I don't understand is:
when this abstract closure gets called, isn't the execution context associated with itself the running execution context? Wouldn't this abstract closure suspend itself then?
I believe so because .then [[27.2.5.4.1 PerformPromiseThen](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-performpromisethen)] creates jobs via [27.2.2.1 NewPromiseReactionJob](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-newpromisereactionjob) which creates an abstract closure that uses [9.5.3 HostCallJobCallback](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-hostcalljobcallback) to call the handler which in turn must perform [7.3.14 Call](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-call) on it, leading to an invocation of the [[Call]] internal method of the function object ([10.2.1](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist)). This pushes a new execution context on the stack.

What am I misunderstanding? What does *prevContext* actually refer to in 6.2.3.1?

Comment: "*I will refer to the linked version of the specification.*" - the "version" you linked is the working draft, it changes daily. You might want to consider linking a specific stable version instead, especially when referring to sections by number.

Comment: "*Wouldn't this abstract closure suspend itself then?*" - yes it does! Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70663026/1048572) maybe. I do however agree that the language on suspending and resuming execution [could be improved](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/issues/2618).

Comment: @Bergi, oops. Thanks for that. I edit that link to lead to the stable June 2022 edition and made sure that (fortunately) all sections have the numbers written in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem might be the idea that there's an execution context "associated with" the abstract closure. The spec is a bit cagey on this point, but I think it's easier to understand examples like yours if you imagine spec algorithms (including abstract closures) as running "outside" any execution context. This then allows spec algorithms to suspend/resume/push/pop execution contexts without any effect on the running of those algorithms.

Comment: Running spec algorithms outside of "execution contexts" is important, yes, especially when it comes to suspending/resuming. However, abstract closures actually *do* have an execution context, they follow the rules of normal function calls.

Comment: Oh, okay. This makes more sense now. I'm still trying to get a grip of how this works exactly, but I think I'll get there now that I understand this.